# Pine-Script how to run an indicator only on the latest bar and all the previous bars should not follow this indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to write a script to color the background of the latest bar based on the RSI value of the bar and turn all the previous bars background to white irrespective of RSI value.

I am able to get the color of the latest bar based on **If barstate.islast is true** condition however once the new bar is formed the color of the previous bar remains the same, I want it to turn back to white.

I tried using If **barstate.islast is false**, indicating it's not the latest running bar, I set the background color to white.

but still not working.

Can anyone guide on this please.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use ternary conditional operators (`?:`).

For example, the following code will work perfectly fine.

```
bgcolor(barstate.islast ? color.blue: color.white)
```

You just need to change the `color.blue` to the code you already have.
Here is a simple example I just wrote (with transparency included):

```
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)
color_bg = rsi >= 50 ? color.new(color.green, 50) : color.new(color.red, 50)
bgcolor(barstate.islast ? color_bg: color.new(color.white, 50))
```